# How to Setup Multiple Ms bot framework bot using Twilio Studio for WhatsApp

Tags: npm, twilio, botframework, chatbot, whatsapp

There is this [Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botbuildercommunity/adapter-twilio-whatsapp) provided by Bot Community to connect Ms bot to WhatsApp using Twilio which works totally fine.[image: This works fine, How do we achieve the same using Studio?]

To get the details of the request I used WEBHOOK SITE. [image]
I was Just wondering if, we can simulate the exact feature using Twilio Studio and get the connection up.

[image: What should be the Body and Parameters here?]

*How can we set up the connection using Studio?*

Any lead would be helpful.

**Thanks In Advance.**

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here. Are you trying to connect inbound and outbound messages through Twilio Studio to Bot Framework? What have you tried so far and how has it gone? Do you have any code to share, Studio screenshots, or error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @philnash. I just want to know if there a way to connect the same way as WhatsApp sandbox using Studio. If yes, How do I know what details I need to pass to process that post request?

Comment: You can connect incoming WhatsApp messages to Studio by setting the webhook URL for your WhatsApp number (or sandbox) to the [Studio trigger's webhook URL](https://twilio-cms-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/Screen_Shot_2020-11-06_at_12.54.19_PM.width-800.png). Is that what you're looking for?